# sql payment distribution

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query where a certain amount gets distributed to each invoice below based on the account_num and item_order. Also, if partial_payment_allowed is set to 'N' then distribution of the above amount should only happen if the distributed amount is greater than the invoice_amt else it should skip the row and carry on to next invoice of the account.

```
Item_order   inv_amount   Partial_pmt            account_num     cr_amt
1             1256         Y                       12             1000
2             1134         Y                       12             1000
1             800          Y                       13             1200
2             200          N                      13             1200
3             156          N                       13             1200
```

In above data, each account has a cr_amt which can be distributed according to item_order. So after distribution result would be

```
account_num    Item_order  inv_amount  Partial_pmt  Dist_amt    Bal_amt
   12          1             1256        Y          1000        256
   12          2             1134        Y          256         878  
   13          1             800         Y          800         400
   13          2             200         N          200         200   
   13          3             156         N          100         100
```

We are trying to avoid loops, any comments are highly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Only pay if dist_amt > inv_amount.  1000 < 1256.  Why is that first payment made?

Comment: Sorry mike,  fixed the partial pmt flags. Please check now.

Comment: @mathguy He asked a followup question in the comment.  In this version, he needs separate calculations for each distinct `account_num`.  I couldn't easily understand what he was asking from his comment post, so I asked him for a separate question.  I hope that's not an SO foul.

Comment: Oh - OK. But that should be stated clearly in the new post (here).

Comment: In the old question, we didn't have multiple accounts having an  certain amount for distribution. I tried working around sql model clause by using partitions but the query falls apart when  multiple accounts are introduced. I am just looking for any other ways to crack this. I am sorry to cause inconvenience,if you still think its a duplication I will take down this post. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am new to stack, will keep in mind next time before reposting. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I think the desired results you posted are wrong.  In the data for account number 12, you applied a credit of $1000 to an invoice of $1256.  That leaves a `BAL_AMT` of $0, since `BAL_AMT` is the balance left on the credit being applied, not the balance left on the invoice.  The data for account number 13 looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer to this question:
[payment distrubution oracle sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351107/payment-distrubution-oracle-sql-query)

You can still use the SQL `MODEL` clause.  In this version, you need separate calculations for each distinct `account_num`.  You can achieve this using the `PARTITION` keyword of the SQL `MODEL` clause to partition by `account_num`.

Like this (see SQL comments for step-by-step explanation):

```
-- Set up test data (since I don't have your table)
WITH inv_raw (item_order, inv_amount, partial_pmt_allowed, account_num, cr_amt) AS (
SELECT 1, 1256, 'Y', 12, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1134, 'Y', 12, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 800, 'Y', 13, 1200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 200, 'N',13, 1200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 156, 'N',13, 1200 FROM DUAL),
-- Ensure that the column we are ordering by is densely populated
inv_dense (dense_item_order, item_order, inv_amount, partial_pmt_allowed, account_num, cr_amt) AS
( SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY account_num ORDER BY item_order ), item_order, inv_amount, partial_pmt_allowed, account_num, cr_amt FROM inv_raw )
-- Give us a way to input the payment amount
--param AS ( SELECT 1100 p_payment_amount FROM DUAL )
-- The actual query starts here
SELECT 
   account_num,
   item_order,
   inv_amount,
   partial_pmt_allowed,
   applied dist_amount,
   remaining_out balance_amt,
   cr_amt
FROM inv_dense
MODEL
-- We want a completely separate calculation for each distinct account_num
PARTITION BY ( account_num )
-- We'll output one row for each value of dense_item_order.
-- We made item_order "dense" so we can do things like CV()-1 to get the 
--   previous row's values.
DIMENSION BY ( dense_item_order )
MEASURES ( cr_amt, item_order, inv_amount, 
           partial_pmt_allowed, 0 applied, 
           0 remaining_in, 0 remaining_out )
RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
-- The amount carried into the first row is the payment amount
remaining_in[1] = cr_amt[1],
-- The amount carried into subsequent rows is the amount we carried out of the prior row
remaining_in[dense_item_order > 1] = remaining_out[CV()-1],
-- The amount applied depends on whether the amount remaining can cover the invoice
-- and whether partial payments are allowed
applied[ANY] = CASE WHEN remaining_in[CV()] >= inv_amount[CV()] OR partial_pmt_allowed[CV()] = 'Y' THEN LEAST(inv_amount[CV()], remaining_in[CV()]) ELSE 0 END,
-- The amount we carry out is the amount we brought in minus what we applied
remaining_out[ANY] = remaining_in[CV()] - applied[CV()]
)
ORDER BY account_num, item_order;
```